# Merge hundreds of rasters

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, raster-conversion

I am willing to merge hundreds of rasters (around 500) but I cannot find a solution.
I am running on qgis 2.6.1 and I have tried to use gdalbuildvrt. It seems to work for combining 10 rasters for instance, but when loading it says  :

> The process cannot start, the program is missing or you do not have the rights to use it.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include the commands or code you used that resulted in the error?

Comment: Please update your QGIS first, current version is 3.22.

Comment: I did not use any command, I have just tried using the interface from Qgis

Comment: You need to clirify your input formats and output desired in order to guess what can be happening.

Comment: Then your QGIS installation may have some error. QGIS works as a user interface to gdalbuildvrt and now it looks like the program is not found. Hopefully it gets corrected by the same when you update your QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 3):

I dont know why it doesnt work for you but this is helpful when creating the virtual raster.

Use pyqgis to list all rasters, then build a virtual raster.

I've found that building overviews is important if you create a virtual raster with many rasters in it, or QGIS can freeze when you add the finished virtual raster. It is possible to build overviews using the code below.

```
import os
rasterfolder = r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/Hojddata_grid_50_plus/' #This and all subfolders in it will be searched for all files
output_file = r'/home/bera/Desktop/testvrt.vrt'

#Create a list of all rasters, I've got tif files
rasterlist = []
for root, folder, files in os.walk(rasterfolder):
    for file in files:
        #Adjust line below to only list the rasters. For example like below, by filetype and filename.
        #My rasters are named for example nh_62_3.tif. But I also have files named nh_62_3_density.tif in the same folder which I dont want to list
        if file.endswith('.tif') and 'nh' in file and 'dens' not in file:
            print(file)
            rasterlist.append(os.path.join(root, file))

#If you want to build overviews, uncomment rows below. This is going to take some time and potentially consume alot more disk space
#for raster in rasterlist:
#    processing.run("gdal:overviews", {'INPUT':raster,'CLEAN':False,'LEVELS':'','RESAMPLING':0,'FORMAT':1,'EXTRA':''})

processing.run("gdal:buildvirtualraster", {'INPUT':rasterlist,'RESOLUTION':0,
    'SEPARATE':False,'PROJ_DIFFERENCE':False,'ADD_ALPHA':False,'ASSIGN_CRS':None,
        'RESAMPLING':0,'SRC_NODATA':'','EXTRA':'',
        'OUTPUT':output_file})
print('Done')
```

[image]